# cURL response to NSString?

Tags: macos, cocoa, curl, nsstring, libcurl

```
- (IBAction)newSearchToolBarButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"New Search");
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/");
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

}
```

This is my current code.  It works by showing the results in the console, but I want to put it into an NSString.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some mesing around and looking at other sample code I've found a solution that works.  I'm not sure this is the best way to do this... but it does work.

```
- (IBAction)newSearchToolBarButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"New Search");
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    char *msg_in = calloc(1,sizeof(char));

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &msg_in);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, http_get_response);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        NSLog(@"cURL-Res=%u",res);

        //NSLog(@"Buffer=%s",msg_in);

        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithCString:msg_in encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"String=%@",string);

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

}

int http_get_response(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t rxed, char **msg_in)
{
    char *c;

    if (asprintf(&c, "%s%.*s", *msg_in, size * rxed, buffer) == -1) {
        free(*msg_in);
        msg_in = NULL;
        return -1;
    }

    free(*msg_in);
    *msg_in = c;

    return size * rxed;
}
```